# Why doesn't work custom control's paint event in Form.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, paint, onpaint

I have a custom button. `OnPaint` method is working in control's class file but the `Button.Paint` method doesn't work in `Form.cs`. Why does this happen and how can it be fixed?

My code for button:

```
//code...        
public AltoButton()
{     
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint|ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer|ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw|ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor|ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    ForeColor = Color.Black;
    Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Comic Sans MS", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    state = MouseState.Leave;
    transparency = false;
}
#endregion
#region Events
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //code to draw shape and painting
}
//code...
```

code in `Form.cs`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        altoButton1.Paint += altoButton1_Paint;
    }

    void altoButton1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 3, 3, 10, 10);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        altoButton1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution myself. The reason is the I deleted the `base.OnPaint(e)` at the `OnPaint(e)` code block.

The solution is just to add `base.OnPaint(e)`

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  //code to draw shape and painting
  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Comment: If you take a look at [.Net Event Raising Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see the `XXXX` event will be raised by `OnXXXX` and so when you override an `OnXXXX` you should call `base.OnXXXX` to raise the event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the drawing elements on the screen - you should practise doing this to get known more(this is unique in different projects).Excatly you can add element to screen , to the tab etc...Hope it would help you.(Helped me:P)